# Trouble with Java MiniMax

Tags: java, minimax

First of all thanks in advance.

I'm working on a Chequers game using MiniMax. For some reason no matter what, whenever I try to run the following method, it always returns "-1". This is regardless of which side is input and how many pieces are on the board. Surely there is something I'm missing? Hopefully you can help me spot it.

MiniMax double return algorithm:

```
public double miniMax(String side, int depth, PlaySpace board)
    {
        this.board = board;
        this.side = side;
        this.depth = depth;
        ChequersMove[] possibleMoves = null;
        possibleMoves = board.getLegalMoves(side);
        double a;

        if(depth==0 || possibleMoves.length < 1){
            a = evaluateState(board);
            return a;
        }
        if(side.equals("A")){
            a = -10000;
            for(ChequersMove move : possibleMoves){

                PlaySpace child = new PlaySpace(board.returnState());
                child.setState(board.returnState());


                child.moveChequer(move.returnCurrentX(),move.returnCurrentY(),move.returnDestX(),move.returnDestY());

                double val = miniMax("B",depth-1,child);
                a = Math.max(a,val);              
            }
            return a;
        }
        else{
            a = 10000;
            for(ChequersMove move : possibleMoves){

                PlaySpace child = new PlaySpace(board.returnState());
                child.setState(board.returnState());


                child.moveChequer(move.returnCurrentX(),move.returnCurrentY(),move.returnDestX(),move.returnDestY());

                double val = miniMax("A",depth-1,child);
                a = Math.min(a,val);              
            }
            return a;
        }
    }
```

Simple evaluation function:

```
public double evaluateState(PlaySpace board)
    {
        double eval = 0;
        for(int x=0;x<8;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<8;y++){
                if(board.returnState()[x][y]!=null){
                    if(board.returnState()[x][y].returnSide().equals("A")){
                        eval++;
                    }

                    else if(board.returnState()[x][y].returnSide().equals("B")){
                        eval--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return eval;
    }
```

Please let me know if there is any more info I could provided that might help. Again, thank you very much, I look forward to your replies!

Comment: How do you invoke this?  What data do you use to get the result you're seeing?  This will make it easier for others to look at your code, potentially.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the swift replies!

Comment: At the moment I'm not invoking it, simply calling it for testing in itself. I have tried stepping through it with a debugger and also a load of print statements. When I print the evaluation return on each leaf node (the one at the furthest depth) varying numbers do come up, e.g. -1, -2, 0 etc. The problem is that no matter what data is input, it always returns -1 (even though in this case the program should have recognised that -2 is smaller than -1 and returned that instead).

Comment: I've gone through your minimax, and it looks correct. I can just guess that either the evaluation function must have a bug or your test positions you used really have a value of -1